# Which of the following expressions are formulae of statement logic?

Tags: logic

My task is: which of the following expressions are formulae of statement
logic? Justify your answer. If an expression is a formula, in which brackets
are omitted, then rewrite this formula with all the brackets.

```
1. V (p ∨ ¬p)
2. (0 ∧ 1) →  (1 ∨ 0)
3. ƛx.x + x ≠ x
4. (¬(p → q ∧ ¬q → p))
5. p ∨ q ∨ r → p ∧ q ∨ r
6. (((p → q) ∧ p → q)
7. ((p → p) → p) → p → p
8. ¬(p → ¬(q ↔ ¬p))
```

According to the rules I have found:

Syntactic Rules:

1. Any atomic statement is a formula.
2. If ϕand ψare formulas then ¬ϕ, (ϕ ∧ ψ), (ϕ ∨ ψ), (ϕ → ψ) and (ϕ ↔ ψ) are also 
   formulas.
3. There are no other formulas (in Statement Logic).

i can guess:

```
1. not a formula
2. not a formula
3. not a formula
4. (¬(p → q) ∧ (¬(q → p)))
5. (p ∨ q) ∨ r → p ∧ (q ∨ r)
6. (p → q) ∧ (p → q) 
7. ((p → p) → p) → p → p
8. ¬(p → ¬(q ↔ ¬p))
```

Comment: What is your question? (4) has brackets that are not allowed by your syntax; that may or may not be considered a fatal flaw in it, but they should certainly not be in you canonical rewriting of it. (6) has brackets that don't balance. Your renderings of (5), (6), and (7) are not fully bracketed.

Comment: I need somebody to check each statement and correct the mistakes, cause i`m not at all sure that any of these  statements is correct

Answer (score 1):

You’ve got some of it, but there are some mistakes. $(1),(2),(3)$, and $(8)$ are correct.

$(4)$ is probably intended to be $\neg((p\to q)\land(\neg q\to p))$, not $(\neg(p\to q)\land\neg(q\to p))$, which is the corrected version of your answer. You have an unwanted pair of parentheses around $\neg(q\to p)$: note that $\neg\varphi$ doesn’t require surrounding parentheses. If it’s really ill-formed, it might be intended to be $(\neg(p\to q)\land(\neg q\to p))$.

$(5)$ requires more parentheses: **every** binary connective together with its arguments is surrounded by a pair. There are different ways to associate the expressions; the one closest to what you have is $\big(((p\lor q)\lor r)\to(p\land(q\lor r))\big)$.

$(6)$ is almost right: you’re just missing the parentheses surrounding the whole thing, to match the $\land$ in the middle. Make it $((p\to q)\land(p\to q))$.

In $(7)$ you’re missing two required pairs of parentheses: each of the implications gets a pair, so you should have $((((p\to p)\to p)\to p)\to p)$, though $(((p\to p)\to p)\to(p\to p))$ is another possible interpretation.

Comment: Thank you, that was really useful

Comment: @user3077612: You’re welcome.

Comment: It's possible that (7) is supposed to be $(((p\to p)\to p)\to(p\to p))$, though. Different authors have different conventions about that.

Comment: (4) can't be what you're suggesting, because the original has a $\neg$ applying to the _entire_ disjunction.

Comment: @Henning: I agree that $(7)$ is ambiguous; it’s not clear that any convention is involved at this point. You’re probably right about $(4)$; it depends on just how ill-formed it is.

Comment: @Brian: I think that "if an expression is a formula, in which brackets are omitted" in the problem statement implies that the OP is expected to apply _some_ convention for omitting brackets that has been stated in the text.

Comment: @Henning: That’s a possible interpretation, but not a necessary one (and not my initial interpretation). You’ve made me wonder now about the ones with excess parens, though.

Comment: I also thought that in statement (4) the negation should be applied the the entire disjunction. 
But anyway it is not really clear if such exercises have only one correct solution, or several solutions are possible.